# Can you restrict workqueue workers from running on certain cores while using a bounded workqueue in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, workqueue

I work on a Control Flow Integrity mechanism that monitors a process. I have been trying to restrict the kernel workqueue workers to certain cores while running the monitored program on an isolated core (Pinned using taskset and isolcpus). But I have been able to do that only with an unbounded workqueue, but I would like to maintain the locality of the workers by using a bounded workqueue while making sure that none of the workers run on the isolated core.
I couldn't find a way to specify the cpu mask when using a bounded workqueue. For now, when I use a bounded workqueue, when I try to pin the monitored process to the isolated core, only the workers that belong to the worker pool of the isolated core are active. (I monitored which core the workers are running on using on the top command).

Is there a way I can restrict workqueue workers from running on certain cores while using a bounded workqueue in linux kernel ?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.13/core-api/workqueue.html - `workqueue_attrs` has `cpumask` field to do exactly what you want. This is not a new feature.

Comment: Yes but the workqueue_attrs can only be used for unbounded workqueue. 
I want it for the bounded workqueue.

Comment: Isn't it too late when WQ is already bound?

Comment: The idea of a bound wq is to run your item on the same cpu the issuer of the task runs on. Thus, you really have only 2 options: 1. make sure your issuing threads don't run on the cpu you don't want 2. don't use bound wq.